# What is wrong with this code? Why does "<identifier> expected" appear as an error?

Tags: graphics, draw, identifier

/*trying to draw the Müller-Lyer
 *illusion using graphics */

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MullerLyerIllusion extends JPanel{

public MullerLyerIllusion(backColor){
setBackground(backColor);
}
```

/*graphics display, various line segments */

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(100, 200, 400, 200); //first line segment
    g.drawLine(80, 180, 100, 200); // left-side arrow tail
    g.drawLine(80, 220, 100, 200); //"            "
    g.drawLine(400, 200, 420, 180); //right-side arrow tail
    g.drawLine(400, 200, 420, 220); //"           "
    g.drawLine(100, 400, 400, 400); //second line segment
    g.drawLine(100, 400, 120, 380); //left-side arrow head
    g.drawLine(100, 400, 120, 420); //"           "
    g.drawLine(380, 380, 400, 400); //right-side arrow head
    g.drawLine(380, 420, 400, 400); //"           "
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the little information provided, I'd guess that you need to specify the parameter type for `backColor`